# How to lookup data based on the next sunday of the week

Tags: php, mysql, date, recurring

I need to lookup a row of data from MySQL based on the next Sunday of the week. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can determine the next sunday using PHP then pass it to your query..

```
$nextSunday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday'));
```

if you need the next sunday from a certain date

```
$date = strtotime('2010-07-01');
$nextSunday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next sunday', $date));
```

The provide this date to your query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '$date'")
```